# the min and the max in raster calculator Arcgis 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, raster-calculator

Can you help me where I can find or how to calculate the minimum and maximum with raster calculator in arcgis 10.1

Answer (score 3):

you can use [zonal statistics as table](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000w8000000.htm) tools to extract the min and max. Just make sure that the zone has the size of your raster.

You can also use the [calculate statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t0000001t000000) tool followed with the ["get raster properties"](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000m7000000.htm) tool (note that calculate statistics may not be necessary because it is often computed when you add the data)

EDIT: for min and max per pixel and for a set of raster, you can use [Cell Statistics](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z0000007q000000.htm). Note that min and max can also be used in map algebra with Python.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I want to calculate the minimum and the maximum of a set of raster data as follows:
S1 = Min ("faspect", "fd2lineam", "d2Froads", "fslope"
"Fd2streams")
S2 = Max ("faspect", "fd2lineam", "d2Froads", "fslope"
"Fd2streams")

Answer (score 2):

You could also use "Con" as a work around. For example if you have Raster_A and Raster_B and interested to find the minimum of two, for the formula use:

```
Con("Rater_A" > "Raster_B", "Raster_B", "Raster_A")
```

You could use this method to expand it with any complicated equation or formula. For example you could easily implement this relationship:

```
Raster_Factor = Min(0.7, Max(0.3, 0.4* Raster_A + 0.2355))
```

By using this formula:

```
Con((0.4 * "Raster_A" * + 0.2355) > 0.7, 0.7, Con((0.4 * "Raster_A" + 0.2355)< 0.3, 0.3 , (0.4 * "Raster_A" + 0.2355)))
```